# How to revert chown command Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, 20.04

I need serious help.

I accidentally ran the command `sudo chown 777 ~` and `sudo chmod 775 ~`, as you can see, in the root directory (~), and now I cannot SSH into my server using my public/private key. What now? What's the default permission of the ~ directory so I can set it back to normal?

Comment: `sudo chown username ~` should be enough to fix.

Comment: @pLumo nope, still doesn't work, I did chmod 775 too remember, new to permissions so don't know much...freaking out a little...

Comment: You must be logged in with the same user as before ...

Comment: @pLumo I am, I haven't ended my ssh session since I did the command

Comment: what is `id -u` output?

Comment: @pLumo it's 1001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chown` changes the **owner** a file or directory, not its permissions.
You ran it on your home directory (`~`), set user id 777 as the owner of that directory. Probably a user with that id does not exist on your system. Subdirectories and files within the directory haven't been touched, because you did not ran the command recursively.

So you can simply change the owner back to your normal user:

```
sudo chown $USER ~
```

(logged in as the same user as before).

or use the users ID (1001 in your case):

```
sudo chown 1001 ~
```

---

`chmod 775` on the home folder is not a real issue. It simply means, that the group has additional write permissions in your home folder. `755` would be the default, change back using:

```
sudo chmod 755 ~
```

Comment: I get: 'chown: invalid user: $USER'

Comment: Should I do a sudo chmod 755 ~ too then as well?

Comment: Do not use single quotes around `$USER` as it will interpret it literally. `$USER` is a variable that translates to the name of the current user when used on the command line or in scripts.

Comment: Life saver! Thank you, I thought I messed the whole system up then as I know how dangerous those commands can be! Thank you @SHawarden too

Comment: you could have, if you had ran it recursively ;-)